# Iterate a list of rows and split

Tags: python, list, split, iteration

I am trying to iterate through a list, then split the rows - to perform a function on specific element in the split.
what i want is something like this - so i can grab each element by postilion x[2] = 220

```
['2', '325', '220', '1.0']
```

what i get is this (split by character)

```
for row in range(len(pln)):
            for j in range(len(pln[row])):
                print( pln[row][j], end="")
                x = [pln[row][j].split()]
                print (x)

2[['2']]
 [['', '']]
3[['3']]
2[['2']]
5[['5']]
 [['', '']]
2[['2']]
2[['2']]
0[['0']]
 [['', '']]
1[['1']]
.[['.']]
0[['0']]

[['\n']]

pln = (before iteration as list)
['2 325 220 1.0\n', '2 600 200 3.3\n', '2 325 100 3.3\n', '2 600 120 5.5\n', '2 600 125 5.5\n', '2 325 100 3.4']

pln = (after iteration)
2 325 220 1.0
2 600 200 3.3
2 325 100 3.3
2 600 120 5.5
2 600 125 5.5
2 325 100 3.4
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: i want to be able to go through the list, split\extract data from each row put in variable for manipulation - repeated for every row.  they way i am splitting is making it by individual characters - i would like the numbers to stay together for extraction.  so for line 2 235 220 1.0  - I would like the 235 to be one character when i split\extract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
lst = ['2 325 220 1.0\n', '2 600 200 3.3\n', '2 325 100 3.3\n', '2 600 120 5.5\n', '2 600 125 5.5\n', '2 325 100 3.4']
result_list = []
for i in lst: 
    k = i.split()
    result_list.append(k)
print(result_list)
#Output: 
[['2', '325', '220', '1.0'], ['2', '600', '200', '3.3'], ['2', '325', '100', '3.3'], ['2', '600', '120', '5.5'], ['2', '600', '125', '5.5'], ['2', '325', '100', '3.4']]
```

You can access an element like:

```
#result_list[row_number][element index]
print(result_list[2][3]) #fourth element in third row  
#Output
3.3
```

You can iterate all rows like:

```
for row in result_list: 
    print(row)

#Output:
['2', '325', '220', '1.0']
['2', '600', '200', '3.3']
['2', '325', '100', '3.3']
['2', '600', '120', '5.5']
['2', '600', '125', '5.5']
['2', '325', '100', '3.4']
```

You can iterate any column like:

```
for row in result_list: 
    print(row[1]) #This will give second column

#Output:
325
600
325
600
600
325
```

Comment: one follow up.  code is great.  but how do i extract from all the lines element 2? I may not always know the number of rows in list so a static extraction like yo suggested would not always work.

Comment: ```result_list[row_number]``` will give you all row. You can iterate the result_list like: ```for row in result_list``` I added the code in answer

Comment: sorry to keep hounding but i am lost.  if i wanted the second element in row 1 and 2 or any row -  325 and 600.  how would i extract them?

Comment: I added how you can iterate columns too.

Comment: I wish i could give you more than one up!  Ty

Answer (score 0):

Stop printing when doing your splitting. Print after the columns have been split.

```py
pln = ['2 325 220 1.0\n', '2 600 200 3.3\n', '2 325 100 3.3\n', '2 600 120 5.5\n', '2 600 125 5.5\n', '2 325 100 3.4']
rows = [line.split() for line in pln]

for row in rows:
    print('\t'.join(row))
```

You can then access each row by its index

```
second_row = rows[1]
```

Then access each column by index

```
third_column = second_row[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will store individual characters in `new_list`
This is all I understood from your question, if anything else do ask.

```
given_list = ['2','325','220','1.0']
new_list = list()
length = len(given_list)
for i in range(length):
    for j in given_list[i]:
        new_list.append(j)
    if i+1 != length:
        new_list.append(",")
print(new_list)
```

Output: `['2', ',', '3', '2', '5', ',', '2', '2', '0', ',', '1', '.', '0']`